# What the problem with background on cordova?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, cordova

I make a mobile app on iOS in Apache Cordova. I have problem with bad background color. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2O0q.png) Its the screenshot od part of interface. And this is div container and its should be a white background and its work good on iOS 15 but in iOS16 looks like in screenshot and its bad because its looks like Brown not white. What's the problem?
Regards

I try to change the CSS parametr but its not work on iOS 16.

Comment: We cannot really help without seeing the relevant code. Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Its only need change one parametr with CSS background -color: white and its work on iOS 15 but not 16 ,   i cannot show all the code

Comment: You should be able to extract just enough code to demonstrate the problem, we don't need the whole page, just the bit that is creating that anomaly.